# RxJS : How to get output from Outer & Inner Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have subscribed to queryparams from which I get the item code. How can we get the data from getItemDetails & getSecuredData together

Instead of using several subscribe(). I have used mergeMap operator

```
this.route.queryParams.pipe(mergeMap( params => {
      const itemCode = params.ItemCode
      return this.dataService.getItemDetails(itemCode)
             .pipe(mergeMap((ItemData) => {
               console.log(ItemData)   // I can see the Item Data
               return this.dataService.getSecureData(itemCode)
             }))
    })).subscribe( response => {
        console.log(response)    // It's blank (Ideally I should get the Item 
                                    Data & SecuredData)
    })
```

Is there anything I'm passing ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can map the outer observable data with inner observable like this to have the final output of the observable which will have outer observable data as well as inner observable:

```
this.route.queryParams
        .pipe(

          //AS PER YOUR NEED YOU CAN USE SWITCHMAP as well
          mergeMap(params => {
                    const itemCode = params.ItemCode
                    return this.dataService.getItemDetails(itemCode)                               
                  }),
          //AS PER YOUR NEED YOU CAN USE SWITCHMAP as well
          mergeMap(itemDetails => {
            return this.dataService.getSecureData(itemCode)
                       .pipe(
                         map(secureData => {
                           return {itemDetails, secureData};
                         })
                       )
          })
        )
    .subscribe( response => {
        //response will have an object which will have two properties 
        //{itemDetails, secureData}
        console.log(response) 
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of a [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) and a [ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

You have to switch from `params.ItemCode` to the fork join so that you fetch the latest from both services since they both depend upon the `ItemCode`. Everytime a new `ItemCode` is emitted the two services will be fetched in parallel, but you only want the first value from each.

```js
   const itemCode$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(map(params => params.ItemCode));
   const itemDetails$ = (itemCode) => this.dataService.getItemDetails(itemCode).pipe(first());
   const secureData$ = (itemCode) => this.dataService.getSecureData(itemCode).pipe(first());

   const value$ = itemCode$.pipe(
      switchMap(itemCode => forkJoin({
          itemCode: of(itemCode),
          itemDetails: itemDetails$(itemCode),
          secureData: secureData$(itemCode)
      }))
  );

  value$.subscribe(value => console.log(value)); // prints {itemCode: xxx, itemDetails: xxx, secureData: xxx}
```

Comment: Ok @Reactgular ! What exactly is switching from params.itemCode to forkjoin & why are we using first() ?